# Telling selenium to stop blocking after expected condition

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am interested in one element, let's call it

```
<div class="ofInterest" some-attr="dataIReallyWant"></div>
```

When I switch off js in firefox, this element does not exist. With javascript it does. I could not tell how it was being generated but my guess is that there is an ajax call which returns a js file which executes this javascript.

I am using selenium but it is very slow. I want to tell Selenium this:

1. Wait for this element to load, i.e something like `EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS, '.ofInterest'))`
2. once you detect said element, stop blocking the code and don't download any further so don't waste my bandwidth

Comment: See [this doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) for your first question. You're halfway there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wait for the element to exist in the DOM, then either quit/close the browser or execute some JavaScript to stop the page from loading:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( #10 second timeout.
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
    # OR
    #driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

More information can be found [here.](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: thanks, although I think `driver.close()` might be better if these requests are in a loop?

Comment: If you're creating a new driver instance every time, yes you'll have to close each time. Otherwise, I suggest simply stopping the page load and using the same instance to make another request.

Comment: by stopping the page you mean `browser.execute_script("window.stop();")`?

Comment: Yes, that will stop any further loading of the same page. This also keeps the driver instance alive so you can reuse it.

Comment: Aggh, you meant to stop loading the page. Sorry, misunderstood the question. Plus one then.

Answer (score 1):

[Explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) were made exactly for what you are describing:

> An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition
>   to occur before proceeding further in the code. The worst case of this
>   is time.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period to
>   wait.

In the worst case scenario, you would wait X amount of seconds that you've passed to the `WebDriverWait`, 10 seconds in this case:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```

But, if the element is found earlier, it would give you the element and stop blocking the execution. By default, it checks for the expected condition every 500ms.

FYI, under-the-hood, it is just [a `while True:` loop](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#57):

```
def until(self, method, message=''):
    """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
    return value is not False."""
    screen = None
    stacktrace = None

    end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
    while True:
        try:
            value = method(self._driver)
            if value:
                return value
        except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
            screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
            stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
        time.sleep(self._poll)
        if time.time() > end_time:
            break
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```